# get currency of Dividend/Split from blapi

Tags: python, bloomberg

I need to get the currency of the dividend/split of actions from the python module to Bloomberg API (blapi). I am using "//blp/refdata" for the Service and "HistoricalDataRequest" for the Request. My request is the following  :

```
refDataService = session.getService("//blp/refdata")
request = refDataService.createRequest("ReferenceDataRequest")
request.getElement("securities").appendValue("HEFV US Equity")
request.getElement("fields").appendValue("DVD_HIST_ALL")
```

It works well I get my results :

```
DVD_HIST_ALL = {
    Declared Date = ...
    Ex-Date = ...
    Record Date = ...
    Payable Date = ...
    Dividend Amount = 1.23456789
    Dividend Frequency = "ok"
    Dividend Type = "ok"
}
```

My problem here is that the currency is not explicitly written. For this company the currency must be CAD not USD but it is not said. How can I get the currency of this action ?

Thank you!

UPDATE : DVD_HIST_ALL does not provide the currency.
So you need to add the field value DVD_CRNCY : 
request.getElement("fields").appendValue("DVD_CRNCY")

Comment: Have you asked HELP HELP?

Comment: If I request DVD_HIST_ALL in the bloomberg console I get the currency ...

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but have you considered querying for ticker + local exchange instead of the composite? (In this case the composite is US).